# Convergent series and integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The following is a small step of a big proof of ''something about primes and zeroes of L-functions'' by Hardy and Littlewood.
[image]

Could somebody help with the following: Why is the assertion circled in red true? (They have given no explanation and I cannot prove it.) I tried comparison with $\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^{\infty}\varphi(t)t^{s-1}dt = \sum a_nn^{-s}$ but this can be divergent (e.g. if $a_n  = n^s$ then $\sum a_ne^{-ny}$ still converges by the Ratio Test). Note that later on they do things with the first integral (not relevant here) so it might be the case that you do not need all assumptions for this minor part.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It tends to $$
\int_{\frac{1}{2}y_0 }^\infty  {\varphi (t)t^{s - 1} dt} 
$$ which is clearly a convergent integral. The integrand is finite at the lower endpoint and tends to zero exponentially fast as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: @Gary Could you give more details please?

Comment: Well, $t\geq y_0/2>0$ and the series for $\phi(t)$ is convergent for all $t>0$. For large $t$, $\varphi (t) = a_1 e^{ - t}  + a_2 e^{ - 2t}  +  \cdots  = \mathcal{O}(e^{ - t} )$, so the improper integral is definitely convergent.

Comment: Ok, $\varphi(t) = O(e^{-t})$ was the most subtle for me to get but now it's fine, thanks!